# WebRTC encryption mechanism of SRTP

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, rtp

WebRTC uses DTLS for encryption of SCTP (data). Furthermore it uses DTLS for key exchange of SRTP (media). But I do not quite understand, whether it also uses DTLS for encryption of SRTP. So my question: ***Does WebRTC use DTLS solely for key exchange (DTLS-SRTP) or does it  encrypt SRTP additionally to its internal encryption mechanism (at least optionally)?***

Why I am asking: 
[RFC 6904](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6904) as well as [RFC 3711](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3711#section-9.4) state that SRTP provides authentication, but not encryption, of the headers of RTP packets. So only the payload of SRTP is encrypted by design.

What confuses me:
Many sources claim WebRTC to be fully end-to-end encrypted.

I am especially interested in the implementation of WebRTC in gstreamer.

Comment: "So only the payload of SRTP is encrypted by design." that's the end-to-end encryption. The RTP payloads are what contain the media and they are encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

DTLS is used for the handshake, but then the keys are extracted and a SRTP context is initialized.

I am not familiar with GStreamer, but in [Pion WebRTC](https://github.com/pion/webrtc) we connect via DTLS [here](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/dtlstransport.go#L280-L284). The WebRTC clients negotiate which side is a DTLS Server and which is a DTLS Client via the SDP.

When the DTLS handshake is complete you then export the keying material, you can see that [here](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/dtlstransport.go#L160-L163)

If you are interested in seeing how SRTP works you can check out [pion/srtp](https://github.com/pion/srtp). It is pretty simple though, it is just AES and then you generate an authentication tag. You can see it all [here](https://github.com/pion/srtp/blob/master/srtp.go#L77)